# CURL Response send to custom URL PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping

```
    public  function amazon_curl_request($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}

  public function amazon(Request  $request)
{
    $url = $request->input('link');
    $parsed_link = parse_url($url);
    $url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=' .$url;
    $url=str_replace(' ', '+', $url);
    $response =  $this->amazon_curl_request($url);        
    return view('FrontEnd/amazon/result_page', compact('response'));
}
```

here is route `Route::get('/amazon/search', [AmazonController::class , 'amazon'])->name('search.amazon');`

I need change url, By default it redirects me here [http://localhost:8000/s?k=bag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO9gG.png)

But I need this URL to show response [http://localhost:8000/amazon-search/bag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKo30.png)

It's  an Amazon Scraping site.

Comment: Welcome to SO .. what you have tried and what error you are getting .?

Comment: I am trying to scrap from amazon, it works fine without URL,, CURL response by force redirects me "http://localhost:8000/s?k=bag" here, "s?k=" it's amazon's url Query but want to show result in my custom url like "http://localhost:8000/amazon-search/bag" here bag is the search string

Comment: then don't ` return $response;` this store in variable and use in `bkade` to show data

Comment: put this in question not in here

Comment: can u add your routers as well

Comment: Routes added ...

Comment: you want to redirect to `'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=' .$url` this .?

Comment: no, I am getting data from this url.

Comment: What version of laravel using ?

Comment: VERSION = '8.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

use `Http` as you are using laravel 8  ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

public function amazon(Request  $request)
{
    $url = $request->input('link');
    $parsed_link = parse_url($url);
    $url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=' .$url;
    $url=str_replace(' ', '+', $url);
    $response =  Http::get($url)->body();   // body() function will return html of url   

    echo $response  // as it is already html of amazon or do some datamanipulation here 
    // return view('FrontEnd/amazon/result_page', compact('response'));
}
```

Comment: Same issue... it shows me data in "http://localhost:8000/s?k=bag" this url.. but I need "http://localhost:8000/'/amazon/search" this url..